# Cannot get CSS script to work with Kohana framework

Tags: php, web, frameworks, kohana

I cannot get my CSS stylesheet to work with the Kohana framework that I downloaded and am using.  I have been Googling nonstop for an hour now, and the solutions that others have suggested do not seem to fix my problem. This is the line of code that I have in my `index.php` file:

```
<?php echo HTML::style('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MOOCinator/media/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>
```

I have tried plain HTML as well as using the relative path for the CSS file.  The CSS file's permissions allow it to be read by everyone. My webpage displays exactly as it should in the browser except for the CSS.  Suggestions on how to fix this, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As falinsky stated all css resource files should be included as

```
<?php echo HTML::style('media/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>
```

From the comments under the other answer we 'debugged' the problem.

Your site url is not set correctly. This is how I got things `.gitignore` friendly.

```
// File application/bootstrap.php
$config = include(APPPATH .'config/environment.php');

Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'    => $config['base_url'],
    'index_file'  => $config['index_file'],
));
```

Config file

```
// File application/config/environment.php
return array(
    'base_url'   => 'http://localhost/project/',
    'index_file' => FALSE,
);
```

I made a copy of this file as `example.environment.php`. In my gitignore I have

```
*
!.gitignore
!example.*
```

As to ignore all files except anything starting with `example` and the `.gitignore` file itself.

This is how I manage all my environment specific settings. Cookie, session, encryption hash, database, etc.

Comment: So, to clarify, I should add the first block of code to `application/bootstrap.php` and then create a file `application/config/environment.php`and add the second block of code to it.  Also, could you clarify what you mean by `.gitignore`.  I appreciate your help *a lot*, but I'm not exactly sure what you're suggesting I do.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The `application/bootstrap.php` block should replace the existing block you have for `Kohana::init`. You mentioned github so I assumed you knew what `git` is. If you don't know it I can only suggest to read about it and try it out: http://git-scm.com/ In short: version management system.

Comment: Okay, I got your workaround to work.  I do know what `git` is, but I haven't used `.gitignore` files before; however, I see from a quick Google search that this is a topic that I can easily learn about.  Out of curiosity, do you think this issue will go away once I have the website on an actual web server?  Or is this a bug that needs to be reported to Kohana?

Comment: It is not a bug, or an issue. Kohana leaves that control to you. And if it is, I'd say it's not worth to fix it. Also, if this answered your question, please mark the answer as such :)

Comment: I was able to make the original `bootstrap.php` code work simply by adding `http://` in front of `localhost:888/MOOCinator`.  Thank you *so much* for your help and patience.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo HTML::style('media/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>
```

please read [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/HTML#style) carefully

Comment: I've already tried that, unfortunately -- it still doesn't work.  (That's what I meant by "relative path.")

Comment: `HTML::Style` uses the `URL::base` function so you need to use a relative path to the root of your domain. Can't you just check what `HTML::style('media/css/bootstrap.css');` prints and check if it's the right URL.

Comment: That is the correct way to do it. If it does not work you have not set your environment settings properly.

Comment: @AmazingDreams Okay, I suspected that.  `PECL HTTP Enabled` was the only test that my Kohana didn't pass -- it's message was `Kohana can use the http extension for the Request_Client_External class.` Could this be causing my issue?  @Manuras

Comment: Nope, it is the site url that would be causing issues with these kinds of things. If that is not set properly you'd for example see something like `http://localhost/media/css/bootstrap.css` instead of the proper `http://localhost/<PROJECT>/media/css/bootstrap.css`. Check your `bootstrap.php` and see if it is set correctly.

Comment: @AmazingDreams My URL is `http://localhost:8888/MOOCinator/`.  All of the HTML elements appear properly except for the CSS.  Further thoughts?

Comment: How does the URL look like? Please also include it in your original question.

Comment: @AmazingDreams That URL by which I access my site is `http://localhost:8888/MOOCinator/`.  My site is not currently hosted on the Internet -- I'm using a local MAMP server.

Comment: I mean the URL that is generated by `HTML::style()`

Comment: @AmazingDreams Oh, I gotcha -- it's `localhost:8888/MOOCinator/media/css/bootstrap.css`.  When I copy and past this URL into the search bar, it does correctly link to the CSS file.

Comment: Well that's weird. Is it missing the `http://`? Check firebug or chrome and see if you get any 404 errors and where the browser is looking for.

Comment: @AmazingDreams So if I just use the HTML code (generated by the `HTML::style()`) but prepend the `localhost:8888/MOOCinator/media/css/bootstrap.css` with `http://`, the CSS works (yay!).  I'd nevertheless like to use a less specific version of this so that others could see this site from GitHub.  Do you have suggestions for this?

Comment: Yes, I suggest adding the `http://` to the siteurl you have set in your bootstrap. This is not normal behaviour and something MUST be wrong in your config files.

Comment: @AmazingDreams So this is a problem with my Kohana framework or with my own `bootstrap.php` or `.htaccess` file(s)?

Comment: It is probably in your bootstrap. You said something about github. Is the source on there?

Comment: @AmazingDreams No, not yet, but it is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kVZJwQVweQ6S5SyO7AV96Wyu-GmpcoKpoefE8OTwXOE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No, I have got no writing permissions. Check out my answer and you can do it yourself.